# Are kurtosis and skewness meaningful for comparing distributions such as gamma distributions with very pronounced shape parameters?

Tags: gamma-distribution, skewness, kurtosis

[image]Are kurtosis and skewness meaningful for comparing distributions such as gamma distributions with very pronounced shape parameters? For instance, take the red distribution in the first plot here:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_distribution

I have two datasets for which the histogram plots look very similar to each other and to that (red) pdf. When I compute the kurtosis and skewness, however, the values are very different. Applying Kolgomorov-Smirnov tests for the equality of distributions, however, strongly fails to reject the null of equality (p-value is 0.27). I am bit puzzled by the apparent failure of kurtosis and skewness...

Comment: The "red" distribution you single out on the Wikipedia page (not a helpful citation for those who struggle with red and green) is that special case of the gamma known as the exponential. It has a skewness of 2 and kurtosis of 9, which aren't especially large. But you'd get useful intuition for how those measures behave in samples of the size you have by simulation. @whuber's comments thus apply specifically as well as generally. Kolmogorov-Smirnov [NB spelling] is in my view not nearly so useful here as a quantile-quantile plot.

Comment: @Glen_b I have 20 bins in intervals of 5%. For the subsample, the kurtosis is 4.38 and skewness is 1.97. for the sample, the skewness is 1.29 and kurtosis is 1.13. I think that the difference in Kurtosis is quite pronounced, am I correct?

Comment: For count proportions I wouldn't consider a gamma as an example -- maybe a scaled binomial (or mixture of scaled binomials). What are the sample sizes of the individual proportions?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/42427/discussion-on-question-by-daniel-pinto-are-kurtosis-and-skewness-meaningful-for).